# How to identify if the current selected row is the last on a gtk.TreeView?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am sorry if this looks a trivial question but I am still new to the complexity of the View/model/store scheme require to use the GTK Treeview.
How to identify if the current selected item is the last item on a gtk.TreeView ?
I don't have children so  right now each node is just a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that, you have to ask the *view* what row is selected, then ask the *model* whether that row is the last one. Like so:

```
selection = view.get_selection()
model, iter = selection.get_selected()
if iter is None:
    print "Nothing selected"
else:
    if model.iter_next(iter) is not None:
        print "Selected item was not last"
    else:
        print "Selected item was last"
```